# FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(myFocusNode) vs myFocusNode.requestFocus();

Tags: flutter

What's the difference between `FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(myFocusNode)` and `myFocusNode.requestFocus()`?

The first one appears to be a lot more complicated, but it's on the [forms coobook](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/focus). The second looks a lot simpler, but the only docs I can find is at its own API docs, which makes me wonder why the first one is the "recommended" one.

Comment: You don't actually need to pass an argument to `requestFocus` using `FocusScope`.

Comment: I copied the example in the cookbook, I think there it passes the argument so that the TextField is focused and not the containing widget?